# Stylus replace long @media line with a keyword

Tags: media-queries, stylus

Is it possible in Stylus to define a keyword/variable to be used instead of a long @media line-rule?

For instance:

```
IE = @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm)
```

And then use it as

```
.div1
    IE
        color red
```

Comment: Note: the media here is for Chrome, not IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, something like this:

```
IE = 'all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm)'

.div1
  @media IE
    color red
```